# Does lazy_static run more than once when used in a parallel iterator?

Tags: rust

I have a utility function that does some regex stuff and am using a `lazy_static` within it as per the [documentation](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/index.html#example-avoid-compiling-the-same-regex-in-a-loop) of Regex. However, this function is only called in a `par_iter` loop like so:

```
fn some_regex_thing(&str) -> String {
   lazy_static! {
        static ref RE: Regex = ...
   }
   RE.replace_all(...)
}

fn main() {
// SNIP

   let output = my_par_vec.par_iter().map(|f| {
                some_regex_thing(f)
               }).collect();
}
```

Does the benefit of `lazy_static` still apply here? Or because this is spawned to different threads, each thread still compiles this, negating the benefit of `lazy_static`?

Comment: Are you sure that's running more than once? From the documentation: "The `Deref` implementation uses a hidden static variable that is guarded by an **atomic check** on each access."

Comment: I'm not, and update the the title to be more specific. That's really what I'd like to know, whether it runs more than once.

Comment: The documentation strongly suggests that never happens. That's what the atomic check is for.

Comment: I'm still new to rust and not too familiar with the atomic checks. I'll read up on that. Thank you!

Comment: An atomic check is the backbone of a mutex. It's how you write thread-safe code.

Comment: Atomics are not specific to Rust, it's a general thread-safe mechanism.

Comment: nit: it's preferred that you use [`once_cell::sync::Lazy`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/sync/struct.Lazy.html) instead of `lazy_static` now.